# Is there a way to specific a custom string id generator with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net5

I have an app that is written on the top on .NET 5 Framework using C#. I am using Entity Framework as my ORM. How can I change the default string id generator?

I want to use this custom [unique id generator](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/blob/main/src/OrchardCore/OrchardCore.Infrastructure/Entities/DefaultIdGenerator.cs) to generate id for string type.

So if I have this model class:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Before the product is added, I want to use my custom generator to auto assign the id to the product. I know I can do this manually every time I want to add a product. But, I am looking for a way to do it with Entity Framework directly so I am not manually setting the ids.

How can I change/set a custom string id generator for Entity Framework?

Answer (score 3):

You can set [custom value generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder.hasvaluegenerator?view=efcore-6.0) for entity property

```cs
entity
  .Property(e => e.Id)
  .HasValueGenerator<CustomStringValueGenerator>();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. OP asked for a 'custom' implementation.  This should be marked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to override [SaveChanges()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechanges?view=efcore-5.0).

Note you also have to mark the ID as DatabaseGenerated, eg

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(c => c.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

or EF will not allow you to track an entity with a null key value.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. Can you help me understand how would I use SaveChange() to set the value? I am actually reading the EF code and I see this that I can possibly override the (ValueGeneratorSelector)[https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/0ba16959c7c4f38f9162101966a6f863ba707120/src/EFCore/ValueGeneration/ValueGeneratorSelector.cs#L126]. I think this will allow me to return a custom string generator. But, the `Create()` method is not called unless `CreateFromFactory` returns null. Instead of overriding, how can I register a custom Value-generator-factory for a string?

Comment: In SaveChanges you can inspect and modify the entities in the change tracker.  So iterate the added entities of the target type and set their keys before calling base.SaveChanges().

Comment: So when I do `dbContent.Products.Add(new Product(){ Name = "Book" });` I get the following error `InvalidOperationException: Unable to track an entity of type 'Product' because its primary key property 'Id' is null.` This happens before `SaveChanges()` is called.